# Rails jquery-ui-rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am working with the jquery-ui-rails gem.  I created a contact form that display a jquery ui dialog when a user clicks a link.  In turn, I have a development and a production server.  On the development server the contact form appears in a jquery ui dialog when I click a link. However, on the production website when I click the link the dialog box with the contact form does not appear.  The code is the same as it is on the development server.

I have tried copied the app folder to dev server, gem file, etc.

I run the following

-bundle install
-rake assets:clean
-rake assets:precompile
-restart server

This works perfectly on the development server.

I follow the same steps on the production server and the link does not work.

I am really at a loss here.  This is the whole point of have a development server.  This basically tells me nothing.

Here's some code snippets:

Gem file:

```
 gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.1.4"

 gem 'jquery-ui-rails', "~> 3.0.0"
```

Link:

```
 <%= link_to "Contact Us", "javascript:void(0)", :id => "contact-link" %>
```

Application js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#contact-link').click(function(){
    $('#contact-form-wrap').show();
    $("#contact-form-wrap").dialog({
        title: "Contact Us",
        height: 420,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Send": function() {
                if($('#contact_subject').val().length != 0 && $('#contact_message').val().length != 0)  {
                    $('#contact-form').submit();
                }
                else {
                    $('#contact-error').html("You must select a subject and enter a message.");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Please advise. I am really limited with what I can do in production.  I cannot keep messing up the website.

Edit:

This is what my application js file looks like now:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require jquery.ui.core
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 //= require active_admin
 //= require contractor_validate
 //= require painter_validate
 //= require jquery.social.media.tabs.1.6
 //= require jquery.validate.min
 //= require payment
 //= require the-tooltip
 //= require general
 //= require_self
```

General.js now contains the code I removed from application.js.

Comment: just check the page resources to confirm that everything is loaded.

Comment: Hi, searched for "contact-link" the above code is there.  I also search for ui related code "ui" and it's in the compiled application.js file.  This is crazy.

Comment: Okay got it working. I wish I new how.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move your js code from `application.js` to some other file , for example contact_form.js (in `app/assets/javascripts/` directory) . The `application.js` has a special purpose - it is a manifest file . I think it would be OK if you place in you manifest file routines like these:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

More about asset-pipeline management you can read [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I'm not sure what difference it will make.